# Does google maps auto-complete always return a comma-separated address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I thought of this really weird 'hack' just now, and I would like to ask some concerns regarding it. Does google maps autocomplete always return a comma-separated address, except for the country / city name ? I have an app here where the bounds are set only around AU.

Although it concerns me that this may not be a good practice, but I would just like to ask if it does return this type of address. Thanks!

Comment: there is no documentation which says what the value returned will be csv format .  but in my practice i have never saw a value returned without a comma. it will be place name , then state name, then country name. so use this hack but be careful to handle the error might happen.

Answer (score 0):

The address formatting may be a really tricky subject. I can suggest reading the following article to get some understanding of the complexity of this question:

https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/